# Can ray_cast ignore objects hidden from view when in local view

Tags: python

Using this code: (can't remember where I got it from)

```
def cast_ray(self, context, event):
    scene = context.scene
    region = context.region
    rv3d = context.region_data
    coord = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
    viewlayer = context.view_layer
    if bpy.app.version >= (2, 91, 0):  # well actually under 2.93 but I let it
        viewlayer = viewlayer.depsgraph
    # get the ray from the viewport and mouse
    view_vector = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_vector_3d(region, rv3d, coord)
    ray_origin = view3d_utils.region_2d_to_origin_3d(region, rv3d, coord)

    return scene.ray_cast(viewlayer, ray_origin, view_vector)
```

it will return a hit on objects that are not visible in the viewport when in local view mode. The objects that are not in local view still have `obj.hide_get()` set as `True` so I'm assuming that's why that get included in the ray_cast.

Can `scene.ray_cast` be made to ignore these objects? Or do I have to `obj.hide_set(True)` them and then reinstate their hide state once my operator finishes?

Comment: What is it about your code that is making it only return a hit on non-visible objects? I don't see it here or anywhere in the documentation that this is how that function works.

Comment: @Jakemoyo, agreed! I can't find anywhere either, it's why I'm "assuming" it's because of the `obj.hide_get()` being `True`. If I mouse over where other objects are in the view (that can't be seen because it's in local view) it returns that object as a hit when called with `result, face_location, face_normal, index, object, matrix = self.cast_ray(context, event)`

Comment: ***update to above comment***
@Jakemoyo, agreed! I can't find anywhere either, it's why I'm "assuming" it's because of the `obj.hide_get()` being `True`. It's not "only" returning a hit on non-visible objects, it returns a hit on all objects with `obj.hide_get()` being `True`. If I mouse over where any objects are in the view (that can't be seen because it's in local view) it returns that object as a hit when called with `result, location, normal, index, object, matrix = self.cast_ray(context, event)`, it also returns a hit on objects that are visible in local view.

Comment: So why not just take the list of hit objects and filter it to get only the visibles? Something like `hit_list = scene.ray_cast(viewlayer, ray_origin, view_vector); visible_list = [obj for obj in hit_list if not obj.hide_viewport]`.

Comment: I have a work around that I use in another script for collecting all visible objects and hiding them, then unhiding them when done, I was just wondering if ray_cast can do this for me in local view. I do like your approach, but would need to check if `obj` is in local view as `obj.hide_viewport` does not change in local view.